# Long limits overhang and cause a symbol to become too wide

Tags: spacing, horizontal-alignment, positioning, subscripts

Sometimes I need to make a union with a long subscript specifier at the bottom like so:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
  \begin{equation*}
    \bigcup_{a \in \{\text{set that is very wide}\}} S_a
  \end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

The problem is that this produces:
[image]

How do I move the S_a over to the left?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `\smashoperator` command, from `mathtools`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

  \begin{equation*}
    \smashoperator{\bigcup_{a \in \{\text{set that is very wide}\}}} S_a
  \end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]